# How to know what the inheritance line of a class is in ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance

if `class C <  B` and `class B <  A`

is there a command to know that C inherits B which inherits A?

Comment: -1. You cannot define classes named `a`, `b`, or `c`, hence there would be no such classes.

Comment: the names are obviously examples to illustrate the situation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
class A; end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end

C.ancestors # => [C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Class.superclass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass)

```
class A; end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end

C.superclass            # => B
C.superclass.superclass # => A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_a?` to test if an object inherited from a class.

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

b = B.new
b.is_a? B   # true
b.is_a? A   # true
```